# How to bind boolean to GridViewColumn checkboxes (have code but doesn't work)?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, listview, gridviewcolumn

I am trying to bind a bool value to checkboxes in a `GridViewColumn`, but it doesn't work. I even tried just returning false, but the checkboxes still look enabled. It only works if I type "False" into the xaml.

The binded property is:

```
public bool HasPermissions
{
    get { return this.UserPrivileges == UserPrivileges.FullAccess; }
}
```

Current value of `this.UserPrivileges` is not `UserPrivileges.FullAccess`.

Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="EffectsWindow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Effects Manager"
        Width="800"
        Height="500"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <DockPanel.Resources>

        <ListView x:Name="EffectsListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AllEffects}">

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn Width="50" Header="Override">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Margin="0"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          IsEnabled="{Binding HasPermission}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

EDIT: Current property code:

```
public bool HasPermissions
{
    get { return this.UserPermissions == UserPermissions.FullAccess; }
    set { this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "HasPermissions" ); }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't implement it. I thought INotifyPropertyChanged is only needed if it's 2 way binding? Like if the value is only defined once, do you still need it?

Comment: Sorry also meant to say, this property can't be set, only get.

Comment: Yes you do need that as long as you want to reflect changes in your property out to the UI. Try it. Let us know if it worked or not.

Comment: In that case what you want to do is in the Setter of UserPriviliges property call OnNotifyPropertyChanged("HasPermissions")

Comment: Thanks, will try that now. Btw I made this property because I couldn't figure out how to bind to an enum property. Can you also show me how to do that, so I can bind it like: UserPrivileges == UserPrivileges.FullAccess, in the xaml. Or is that a bad practice?

Comment: I added the new property to the question, is this how you meant?

Comment: Also not sure if it matters but the same checkboxes' IsChecked property is also data binded. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the problem in your updated property: that property has no backing field, its getter returns the result of comparing a different property with `UserPermissions.FullAccess`. Therefore it can never *be* set.

The thing to focus on is, when does the UI need to be notified that the value returned by `HasPermissions` has changed? Well, when *can* that value change? When the value of `this.UserPermissions` changes, right?

Assuming `this.UserPermissions` is itself a property with a setter, **its setter** is the place to call `RaisePropertyChanged("HasPermissions")`. That will tell the UI that, even if it doesn't bind to `UserPermissions` directly, the property it *does* bind to must be re-evaluated.

**Update:** Regarding your comment, `IsChecked` is indeed the CheckBox property you should bind `HasPermissions` to if you want the box's checked state to indicate that the user has permission.

**Update the 2nd:** It sounds like you want to access a property of the Window's DataContext from a visual child (the ListBox). You can use a RelativeSource binding to achieve that, like so:

```
<CheckBox Margin="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.HasPermission}"/>
```

That somewhat clunky notation will find the nearest parent element to the CheckBox in the visual tree that is of type Window, and bind to its DataContext property to find HasPermission.

Comment: Thanks, the IsChecked actually represent whether the effect is active or not which uses another binding, but I want some people to be able to modify these values, not everyone. That's why I use IsEnabled too. I tried what you said, but still the checkboxes are enabled, but the HasPermission property returns False. Also I set UserPermissions in the constructor of this object. Does that matter?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. It's confusing. I have a VM class for the whole window, and this VM class called EditorVM has the observable collection which the ListView is binded to. But the property HasPermission is on this EditorVM, not EditorVM.AllEffects. Because the property is global, not per instance of Effect. How do you think I can bind these checkboxes to EditorVM for the IsEnabled property? Does it make sense?

Comment: Or do you think I have to Bind the ListView to EditorVM and use AllEffects.PropertyName notation for every other binding, to allow me to address the HasPermissions property?

Comment: @Joan Venge If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you want to access a property of the Window's DataContext from a visual child (the ListBox). See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, since the problem was unique enough I made another question about this specifically. Hope this gives you more detail about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332213/how-to-bind-to-2-different-members-in-a-class-in-wpf